# Bad idea to override getContext() to non-null in Android api level 27?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-context

I'm using kotlin, and recently updated my application with compileSdkVersion/targetSdkVersion 27. There I get some compilation errors, where for instance, context is now nullable(context?) instead of non-null. 
I have a base fragment class, that other fragments inherits from. Is it a bad idea to have this function?

```
override fun getContext(): Context {
    return super.getContext()!!
}
```

In the parent function, I see that you have this code:

```
/**
 * Return the {@link Context} this fragment is currently associated with.
 */
@Nullable
public Context getContext() {
    return mHost == null ? null : mHost.getContext();
}
```

Where mHost is:

```
// Host this fragment is attached to.
FragmentHostCallback mHost;
```

But the fragment will always be attached to a host, as far as I can see. 
Is there any kind of scenario where mHost will be null?

Edit: In support library v27.1.0 Fragments now have requireContext(), requireActivity(), requireHost(), and requireFragmentManager() methods, which return a NonNull object of the equivalent get methods or throw an IllegalStateException.

See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#requireContext()

Comment: Maybe if the fragment loose it state, best guess I can give

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason being there are cases where fragments won't be attached to the parent yet but you try to access it,in such case context will be null.Best example is when you have tabs with multiple fragments and you keep switching between the tabs, most possible case is fragments will be detached and take time to attach it back but you have already switched to other tabs resulting your app to crash. So keeping context nullable is one of the best practice.

Comment: Thanks, good example. I actually use a FragmentPagerAdapter, so the issue might actually occur there.

Answer (score 3):

There can be situations where the fragment is not attached to a host. The simplest example is when the fragment is instantiated with its empty constructor and is not attached to anything. If you called `getContext()` in the constructor (or a method called from the constructor), it would result in a `null` value.

This means that overriding `getContext()` to return `super.getContext()` would make no sense. You might be able get rid of some *null-checks* but if it's `null`, your app will crash.

Comment: Thanks for your response.